# Get the item index of a listview and delete it on the listview and on my database

Tags: android

I'm now currently working on a project that lets the user view the list of a certain table and has the privilege of either editing or deleting it. There's no error, I just don't have any idea on what to do. Maybe anyone could help me on even just the delete feature? Giving a sample code would be so much helpful. Here's my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
String DB_PATH = null;

private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
private Runnable viewOrders;
int totalId, totalProdId, totalQty, totalBigQty, totalUnitQty;

Cursor cursorProduct;

String id = "";
String productid = "";
String qty = "";
String bigqty = "";
String unitqty = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dc_invviewlist);

    copyDB();

    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH,null);

    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.dc_inventory_viewlist, m_orders);
    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DC_invviewlist.this,
            "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private void getOrders(){
    try{
        String i = getPIViewListId();
        String pi = getPIViewListProdId();
        String q = getPIViewListQty();
        String bq = getPIViewListBigQty();
        String uq = getPIViewListUnitQty();

        String[] iValue = i.split("~");
        String[] piValue = pi.split("~");
        String[] qValue = q.split("~");
        String[] bqValue = bq.split("~");
        String[] uqValue = uq.split("~");

        totalId = iValue.length;
        totalProdId = piValue.length;
        totalQty = qValue.length;
        totalBigQty = bqValue.length;
        totalUnitQty = uqValue.length;

        m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        for (int j = 0; j < totalId; j++) {
            Order o = new Order();
            o.setOrderId(iValue[j]);
            o.setOrderProdId(piValue[j]);
            o.setOrderQty(qValue[j]);
            o.setOrderBigQty(bqValue[j]);
            o.setOrderUnitQty(uqValue[j]);
            m_orders.add(o);
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}


private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.dc_inventory_viewlist, null);
        }
        Order o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInvViewListId);
            TextView prodid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInvViewListProductId);
            TextView qty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInvViewListQty);
            TextView bigqty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInvViewListBigQty);
            TextView unitqty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInvViewListUnitQty);

            if (id != null) {
                id.setText(o.getOrderId());                            }
            if(prodid != null){
                prodid.setText(o.getOrderProdId());
            }
            if(qty != null){
                qty.setText(o.getOrderQty());
            }
            if(bigqty != null){
                bigqty.setText(o.getOrderBigQty());
            }
            if(unitqty != null){
                unitqty.setText(o.getOrderUnitQty());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public void copyDB(){
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        DB_PATH = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    }
    else{
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    File dbdir = new File(DB_PATH);
    if(!dbdir.exists()){
        dbdir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(DB_PATH+"DC");

    if(!file.exists()){
        try{
            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("DC");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ throw new RuntimeException(e);};
    }

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        DB_PATH = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/DC";
    }else{
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/DC";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myDataBase.close();
}

public String getPIViewListId(){
    cursorProduct = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from tblProductInvAdjust", null);
    if (cursorProduct.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id += ""+cursorProduct.getString(0)+"~";
        } while (cursorProduct.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursorProduct != null && !cursorProduct.isClosed()) {
        cursorProduct.close();
    }
    return id;
}

public String getPIViewListProdId(){
    cursorProduct = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from tblProductInvAdjust", null);
    if (cursorProduct.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            productid += ""+cursorProduct.getString(1)+"~";
        } while (cursorProduct.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursorProduct != null && !cursorProduct.isClosed()) {
        cursorProduct.close();
    }
    return productid;
}

public String getPIViewListQty(){
    cursorProduct = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from tblProductInvAdjust", null);
    if (cursorProduct.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            qty += ""+cursorProduct.getString(2)+"~";
        } while (cursorProduct.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursorProduct != null && !cursorProduct.isClosed()) {
        cursorProduct.close();
    }
    return qty;
}

public String getPIViewListBigQty(){
    cursorProduct = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from tblProductInvAdjust", null);
    if (cursorProduct.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            bigqty += ""+cursorProduct.getString(3)+"~";
        } while (cursorProduct.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursorProduct != null && !cursorProduct.isClosed()) {
        cursorProduct.close();
    }
    return bigqty;
}

public String getPIViewListUnitQty(){
    cursorProduct = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from tblProductInvAdjust", null);
    if (cursorProduct.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            unitqty += ""+cursorProduct.getString(4)+"~";
        } while (cursorProduct.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursorProduct != null && !cursorProduct.isClosed()) {
        cursorProduct.close();
    }
    return unitqty;
}

final int CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM =1;
final int CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE =2;
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM, Menu.NONE, "Edit");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT_ITEM:
            //do smth
            return(true);
        case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:
            myDataBase.execSQL("DELETE FROM tblProductInvAdjust");
            return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

I hope anyone could help me on this. I really need a help right now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
   sql_lite_db_obj.delete(tablename, whereClause, whereArgs)
```

For your convenience i edited my answer

```
public void clickHandler(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.deleteOrder) {

int _id = 0;          
try {               
    _id = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.orderTitle);       
} catch (Exception e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();                
}    


dh.delete(DatabaseHelpere.TableNAME, "_id=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(_id) });
}
}
```

Comment: How could I get the index id of the item? In one item, I've used five textviews for five columns per record. Maybe if I could get the value of the textview containg the id of the corresponding item on the listview I could use that on my whereClause. But I don't really have an idea on what to do. I hope you'll still respond. Thanks for the earlier response, btw. :)

Comment: @AdurUrbano . I have edited my answer.  Take look and still have doubt , let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't set id=0 though, set it null and check for null before you run query

Comment: @BlueGreen. I don't really get it. What are you referring on deleteOrder and orderTitle? and where am I going to call this class? Thanks for the time. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Sorry @BlueGreen. Just a student and really new to these stuffs. Glad you're there to help. :)

Comment: Here deleteOrder is xml id of android widget on which click you want to delete row from db. And you need to call these inside click event of android widget.